# How to get callback after in app purchase in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

My application can buy in-app products from Play store and itunes.

However I would like to get notification that the payment was successful.

How can I achieve this? Currently the product is bought and that is all.

I know that there is a `PurchaseCallback` interface which can be implemented but the `paymentSucceeded()` method is for manual payments.

Sample scenario:

I buy the product from store, then I listen for success response. Then based on response. Display something or do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the callback `itemPurchased(String s)` with the appropriate SKU when the payment succeeds. You can test this in the simulator where you get the appropriate prompts.

Comment: Thanks so much the simulator tip gave me the breakthrough I needed. This gives me an understanding of how to resolve my ios wasPurchased issues on previous threads. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get this callback ? `purchase()` method does not take any callback as parameter ? So how would you set this up, would you mind elaborating a bit further ?

Comment: The main class needs to implement that interface, notice that the main class is not the state machine but the actual "main" class with the start(), init(Object) methods in it.